# Symfony 4 : The type hint of parameter is invalid

Tags: symfony, type-hinting

I'm getting this error when trying to clear cache and composer install in prod server :

> !!    The type hint of parameter "show" in method "addShow" in class
>   "App\Entity\   !!    Type" is invalid.

this is the addShow method :

```
   public function addShow(Show $show): self
    {
        if (!$this->shows->contains($show)) {
            $this->shows[] = $show;
            $show->setType($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: looks sensible, as long as you actually have a `Show` entity in the same namespace (or have an appropriate use clause). I hope the Show entity isn't new and not yet deployed? ^^

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify class that you passing as parameter.

You can put all path to class to specify the type:

```
public function addShow(App\Bundle\Show $show): self
 {
     if (!$this->shows->contains($show)) {
         $this->shows[] = $show;
         $show->setType($this);
     }

    return $this;
 }
```

or add:

```
use App\Bundle\Show;
```